# htaccess file restriction

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a directory on my webserver. It does not have an index page. so when u access the directory via a web browser it lists the files in it. Now i want to create a htaccess file that can block the directory listing so that when you access it via the web browser, the files in the directory would not be listed but would be able to access the files by appending the name of the file you wish to access to the url making it a full part to the file. Also the htaccess file should be able to restrict access from all but files with a particular extention. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Options -Indexes

Order allow,deny
Deny from all

<Files "*.gif">
    Allow from all
    Deny from none
</Files>
```

Comment: thanks for the response. And if i want to include multple viewable files, can i seperate them with |

Comment: Right, with regex: <Files ~ "\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">. That example is directly from the Apache docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#files

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off the file listing for a particular directory in the directory's .htaccess with

```
Options -Indexes
```

OR

You could just put an empty index.html file in the directory you want to protect.

Answer (score -1):

In the .htaccess file in your directory just put

```
Options -Indexes
```

As stated before.

Edited to remove the wrong htaccess setting. Again sorry